# How to pass props stated in HTML to root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a simple component in React for two buttons in an existing HTML/JavaScript, **(not a React project)** project. It looks like this:

```
//Submitcancel.jsx
'use strict'

class Submitcancel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-buttons">
                <div className="ibm-col-12-12">
                    <button id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Submit" type="submit" className="ibm-btn-pri dw-btn-blue">Submit</button>
                    <button value="Cancel" id="buttonCancel" name="buttonCancel" className="ibm-btn-sec dw-btn-blue">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    // React.createElement(Submitcancel),
    // document.querySelector('#react-submit-cancel')
)
```

The HTML file looks like this:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- Load React component. -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="./js/components/Submitcancel.jsx"></script>
```

The component element where I would like to define the `props` is like this:

```
<div id="react-submit-cancel"></div>
```

Comment: Pass a props Object as second argument to `React.createElement` [(see here)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: What props do you want to pass? Some values? We need specifics.

Comment: Let's say I want to use the buttons in two different pages, and want the value to be different on each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab the button texts from your HTML `<div>`, you need a non-react solution for that:

```
<div id="react-submit-cancel" submitText="Go"></div>
```

then in your initialization:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#react-submit-cancel');
const props = {
  submitText: el.getAttribute("submitText") || "Submit", // default value
  cancelText: el.getAttribute("cancelText") || "Cancel"
};
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Submitcancel, props), el)
```

For a pure React solution you'd have to wrap the Submitcancel component so you can pass props to it using JSX.

Comment: Seems ok. I'll use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you need to pass data through props, you just need to mention props id and value along with component.

In your case code will be like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Submitcancel FirstName={"first name"} LastName={"last name"}/>,
 document.getElementById("react-submit-cancel")
)
```

Above example **FirstName** and **LastName** are two props

You can get the value in constructor inside the **Submitcancel** component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(props.FirstName)
    console.log(props.LastName)
}
```

Comment: So if I use `<div id="react-submit-cancel"></div>` in two different pages, and want one of the submit button's value to say `Submit` and the other `Go`? Isn't it suppose to be a reusable component?

Comment: You don't need to use div, You can just add   <Submitcancel buttonvalue={"Submit"}/> for submit button and <Submitcancel buttonvalue={"Go"}/> button and handle this into the constructor

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Submitcancel />,
  document.getElementById("react-submit-cancel")
)
```